# How to play a mp3 music using php?

Tags: php, html

I've a directory on the site with several musics.

What I want is to click on a simple button and listen to one of those musics.

Is this possible using php?

Comment: You want it to play on the server or the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is a server-side script that is used more for data processing and interacting with databases. What you're looking for is a client-side script, so using javascript or flash is the better way to play MP3's. There are plenty of free JS and Flash plugins for you to download or install on the internet.

My personal favorite is SoundManager2, 
http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/
which is more of a development type API, for creating and customizing your own applications. It is by far one of the more flexible audio players for its incredibly small optimized builds.

Answer (score 2):

There's this script generator in which you can be able to let your Web page play audio. 
Here is the link:
http://www.scriptgenerator.net/44/Audio-player-script-generator/

Answer (score 2):

You can use HTML5:

```
var snd = new Audio("file.wav"); // buffers automatically when created
snd.play();
```

You can then use onclicks, etc and trigger the `snd.play()`

But looking at your question, I think that HTML5 doesn't support mp3...

Comment: It's browser specific (and maybe even platform specific) whether mp3's can be played.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is not possible using PHP only (since PHP is serverside and I think you want to play clientside). However with either javascript / flash this can easily be done.

If you want to be cool (and don't have to support older user-agents) you could use html5's native [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/audio).

I've had good fun with [AudioManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) which tries to use JS and falls back to flash.

Comment: Soundmanager is too good... i have also created a nice demo if anyone wanna check http://www.thetutlage.com/post=TUT142

Answer (score 0):

Media handling is managed by the browser.  The best way to do this is to put out an HTML page from your PHP with audio embedded, see:-

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp

Without embedding them properly in HTML, the browser will treat them as files for download and then it's up to each browser as to what helper it uses to play them, or whether they are just saved to disk.

Answer (score 0):

ok playing songs directly with php is not the right way or probably you will not even find a secure way to do that, there are some really good options over the net, i mean jquery plugin like jwPlayer and you can search more on google. Which can help you setting up a complete audio player with playlist. But again i am not sure what you have in your mind i have created a simple function that will help you playing songs.

```
<?php

  function getUploadedFiles($directory){
    $folder = opendir($directory);
    while ($file = readdir($folder)) {
    if($file !== '.' && $file !== '..')
    {
        $filename = $directory.'/'.$file;
        $file_array[] = array('filename' => $file);
    }
}
return $file_array;
  }

$music = getUploadedFiles('music');

foreach($music as $value)
{
    echo '<a href="music/'.$value['filename'].'">'.$value['filename'].'</a>';
}

  ?>
```

Function will mostly depend upon the browser or music player installed inside user machine, so it is never right to trust what user is going to have + your file path will be visible.

I still recommend look for a stable jquery html5 plugin which supports flash as a fallback and you can easily setup a complete audio player with playlist.